# How can i launch AWS ECS Service?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ecs

I'm trying to create a ECS Cluster with a service from task definition but get this error:

> Resource handler returned message: "Error occurred during operation 'ECS Deployment Circuit Breaker was triggered'." (RequestToken: 657c3321-f13a-4213-3a8f-267e8865a914, HandlerErrorCode: GeneralServiceException)

The task definition json is:

```
{
  "taskDefinitionArn": "arn:aws:ecs:eu-west-1:317470260945:task-definition/task-alberto-django:1",
  "containerDefinitions": [
    {
      "name": "alberto-django-ctnr",
      "image": "317470260945.dkr.ecr.eu-west-1.amazonaws.com/asm_repository:repo_personal_django",
      "cpu": 0,
      "links": [],
      "portMappings": [
        {
          "containerPort": 80,
          "hostPort": 0,
          "protocol": "tcp"
        }
      ],
      "essential": true,
      "entryPoint": [],
      "command": [],
      "environment": [
        ...
      ],
      "environmentFiles": [],
      "mountPoints": [],
      "volumesFrom": [],
      "secrets": [],
      "dnsServers": [],
      "dnsSearchDomains": [],
      "extraHosts": [],
      "dockerSecurityOptions": [],
      "dockerLabels": {},
      "ulimits": [],
      "systemControls": []
    }
  ],
  "family": "task-alberto-django",
  "executionRoleArn": "arn:aws:iam::317470260945:role/ecsTaskExecutionRole",
  "networkMode": "bridge",
  "revision": 1,
  "volumes": [],
  "status": "ACTIVE",
  "requiresAttributes": [
    {
      "name": "com.amazonaws.ecs.capability.ecr-auth"
    },
    {
      "name": "com.amazonaws.ecs.capability.docker-remote-api.1.17"
    },
    {
      "name": "ecs.capability.execution-role-ecr-pull"
    },
    {
      "name": "com.amazonaws.ecs.capability.docker-remote-api.1.18"
    }
  ],
  "placementConstraints": [],
  "compatibilities": [
    "EXTERNAL",
    "EC2"
  ],
  "requiresCompatibilities": [
    "EC2"
  ],
  "cpu": "1024",
  "memory": "1024",
  "runtimePlatform": {
    "cpuArchitecture": "X86_64",
    "operatingSystemFamily": "LINUX"
  },
  "registeredAt": "2022-10-27T10:15:22.553Z",
  "registeredBy": "arn:aws:iam::317470260945:root",
  "tags": [
    {
      "key": "ecs:taskDefinition:createdFrom",
      "value": "ecs-console-v2"
    },
    {
      "key": "ecs:taskDefinition:stackId",
      "value": "arn:aws:cloudformation:eu-west-1:317470260945:stack/ECS-Console-V2-TaskDefinition-bb050013-6338-4b6e-83a3-54edd1775f3e/41ce7c80-55e0-11ed-bbd1-0add076f7d23"
    }
  ]
}
```

Anybody could help me please ?

Comment: Sounds like you defined a circuit breaker somewhere and it was triggered. Reference: https://aws.amazon.com/de/blogs/containers/announcing-amazon-ecs-deployment-circuit-breaker/

Comment: The circuit breaker only triggers after several failures to deploy a task. That's really just a side-effect of the actual problem. You need to look at the stopped tasks to see why they failed to run. There currently isn't enough information in your question for anyone to help you.

Comment: @MarkB for me stopped tasks don't even exist by the time the circuit breaker is triggered, I'm not sure where to look for the failure.

Comment: The UI by default doesn't show stopped tasks. You have to select the "STOPPED" dropdown in the UI to see the stopped tasks. They will display for a little while after they are stopped. Even after they are gone, the container logs should be available in CloudWatch Logs for you to view. Although it looks like you don't currently have container logging enabled in your task definition, so you need to fix that as well.